# redirect and check login does not do it for me

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, session

Can anyone please see what is wrong?
I have to make a simple login form but I cant get it to show my index1.php page. It gets stuck on my login.function.php page. I know that i somewhere have to put some code for the check_login in my index1.php page but my head is blank. I dont know where to put it or how I should code it. Anyone?

login.function.php

```
    <?php
     session_start(); 

     function login($username, $password) 
     { 
         //rigt user and pw
         $correct_user = "xx1"; 
         $correct_pass = "xx2"; 

 //Step 1 
 if ( !empty($username) && !empty($password) ) 
 { 

     //Steg 2 
     if ( $username == $correct_user  
          && $password == $correct_pass ) 
     { 

          //Steg3 
          $_SESSION['user_login'] = TRUE; 
          header('Location: http://page.com/TEST/index1.php');
    } 
     //if user and pw is wrong 
     else 
     { 
         return "blablabla..."; 
     } 
} 

 //if user and pw is empty 
 else 
 { 
     return "you have to....."; 
         } 

     } 


      /********************************************* 
     * Function to log out
     *********************************************/ 
     function logout() 
     { 
     $_SESSION['user_login'] = FALSE; 
        session_destroy(); 
      } 

      function is_logon() 
       { 
            if ( isset($_SESSION['user_login'])  
               && $_SESSION['user_login'] == TRUE ) 
                { 
                   return TRUE; 
             } 
            else 
               { 
                  return FALSE; 
            } 
           } 

    $usr = $_POST["username"];
    $pwd = $_POST["password"];
    login($usr, $pwd);  
     ?>
```

My index.php

```
         <body>
        <form action="login.function.php" method="post">
       <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
              <tr>
             <td><div align="center">
               <p><img src="../site_images/logo.png" width="340" height="75"></p>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p>
                  </div></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
             <td><div align="center" class="style4">
                 <p>Welcome to... - Please log in </p>
                 <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="center">
               <span class="style4">User name:</span><br>
               <input type="text" name="username"><br>
               <span class="style4">Password:</span><br>
               <input type="password" name="password"><br>
               <input type="hidden" name="login_form" value="1">
               <input type="submit" value="Log in">
            </td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td><div align="center"><img  src="../site_images/wwww.jpg" width="710" height="444"></div></td>
                </tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table>
               </form>
               </body>
                </html>
```

And some of my index1.php

```
             <?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
             include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
              ?>
              <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html><head>
              <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Mon, 27 Jul 1997 00:00:00 GMT" />
             <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache" />
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache" />
          <title>Blablabla</title>
         <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
         <script type="text/javascript">
           <!--
           function openClub(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0  
        window.open(theURL,winName,features);
           }
           </script>
            </head>
            <body bgcolor="#000000">
            <?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
            <div id="pageMiddle">           
        <table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
                  <tr>                 
    <th width="50" align="left">One</th>
                            <th width="200" align="left">Two</th>                
    <th width="75" align="left">Three</th>                
    <th width="160" align="left">Fore</th>                
    <th width="100" align="left">five</th>            
         </tr>
         <?php
        mysqli_set_charset($db_conx, "iso-8859-1"); 
            $query="SELECT * FROM ccc2 WHERE regional = 1 OR regional = 2 ORDER BY one, club ASC"; 
           $result=mysqli_query($db_conx, $query); 
           $num=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
            .............
```

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: How do you mean? :)

Comment: `<table>` needs to be *inside* `<form>`, and not the other way around as you have it now.

Comment: Where are you calling the function login() ?

Comment: Thats my problem. Dont know where and the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add this code at the end of your login.function.php page

```
$usr = $_POST["username"];
$pwd = $_POST["password"];
login($usr, $pwd);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works with the right password now BUT if I try with the wrong one it redirects to a blank side on the login.function.php. Nothing of the errormessages are shown. Sugestion? :)

Comment: I've put the table inside the form now and edited the code above as you can see. No changes

Comment: Sorry for late answer, If you are talking about "blablabla..." & "you have to....." as errormessages, So add ECHO before login($usr, $pwd); `echo 
 login($usr, $pwd);` , Returning values doesn't mean send to the client, you need to print them with ECHO (in php)